# String.find isn;t correctly finding values

Tags: c++, string, find

I am doing part of a project that involves separating strings in C++ and finding things in them. What this part of the code is supposed to do is go through a string of coordinates like:

12 22 N 2 34 W

or

23 43 S 322 12 W

and find the S or W changing boolean Sneg and Wneg variables to true depending on if it finds them in the string. the problem is that it is always returning true for both values in all cases.
in this question "line" is a sting that contains coordinates in the way listed above.

```
#include<fstream>
    string south = 'S';
    string west = 'W';

    size_t found0 = line.find(south);
    if(found0 != std::string::npos)
    {
        char super = line.at(found0);
        if(super =='S')
        {
            Sneg = false;
        }
        else Sneg = true;
    }
    size_t found1 = line.find(west);
    if(found1 != string::npos)
    {
        char duper = line.at(found1);
        if(duper == 'W')
        {
            Wneg = false;
        }
        else Wneg = true;
    }
```

Comment: This won't even compile: `string south = 'S';`

Comment: I can assure that `string::find()` works just fine.  It's not clear from what you posted what you are doing wrong, but you can simplify the setting of `Sneg` to one line of code that's a lot easier to read in my opinion: `Sneg = (line.find('S') == string::npos);` (assuming that you want `Sneg == true` if the letter S is **not** in the line).  Similarly for `Wneg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this does what you want:

```
const char south = 'S', west = 'W';
string line = "12 22 N 2 34 W"; // or some other source
bool Sneg = ( line.find(south) == string::npos );
bool Wneg = ( line.find(west)  == string::npos );
```

there are some problem with your solution, most notably :

1) initializing a string with a char 
2) if the `if` condition would have been false, you dont set the value of `Xneg`.

Comment: "*storing the result of `string::find` in an unsigned type*" is not a problem but fine since `std::npos` is actually of type `size_t` and `string::find` returns `size_t`.

Comment: you are right, I misremembered. Or they changed it. Removed that part